# Binding data from component to view on service return - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I am using angular 8 and I have a variable called `items` in my component file `mycomponent.ts` which is bound to my HTML like below.

My HTML

```
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="items">
    <div *ngFor="let item of items" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="item" (click)="onClick(item)">
    .......
    </div>
</div>
```

Also in that component file it has a function like below.

```
msgFrmServer(update) {
    this.items = update;
}
```

In a service file `myservice.ts` I have the following code to call this function.

```
myComponent.msgFrmServer(update);
```

where I call the function `msgFrmServer` in my component ts file.

The variable gets updated without issues inside the method, but the view does not get updated. This is a websocket application where I get updates from the server and the service class calls the function in the component ts file every time there is an update.

I can move the service class functions inside the component ts and then the things work fine. But that looks like a bad design idea. I would like to keep my services separate and get this working. Can someone please  help me with this? I am new to Angular and I may be missing some good feature in Angular that can easily handle this.

Comment: Can you whip up a small example? Perhaps you need to wait for the data to fully load then add an ngIf on the component, ie *ngIf="dataLoaded"

Comment: @Sprep I have added code inside the question which is from my application. It gets updated many times (every time the server sends an update).

Comment: @Sprep Also the problem is that data binding does not work when the service calls the component ts. Threrefore any variable like "dataLoaded" is also not updated in the view.

Comment: are you using an ngOnInit in your component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use websocket than you can construct WebSocketSubject in your service using rxjs (as in my-test.service in the stackblitz example below). Then you can subscribe to it in your component. If your websocket gets new message than the next function in subsription is invoked and you can than call whatever function you want in your component.

Example of service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { webSocket, WebSocketSubject } from "rxjs/webSocket";

@Injectable()
export class MyTestWebsocketService {
  myWebSocket: WebSocketSubject<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.myWebSocket = webSocket({
      url: "ws://xxxxx/"
    });
  }

  getWebSocket() {
    return this.myWebSocket;
  }
}
```

example of component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { MyTestService } from "../my-test.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-my-component",
  templateUrl: "./my-component.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./my-component.component.css"]
})
export class MyTestComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private myTestService: MyTestService) {}
  items: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myTestService.getWebSocket().subscribe(
      msg => {
        this.msgFrmServer(msg);
      }, // Called whenever there is a message from the server.
      err => console.log(err), // Called if at any point WebSocket API signals some kind of error.
      () => console.log("complete") // Called when connection is closed (for whatever reason).
    );
  }

  msgFrmServer(update) {
    this.items = update;
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tnr8jy?file=src/app/my-component/my-component.component.ts)